# Convert a digit code into datetime format in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe that has a column with a 5 digit code that represent a day and time, and it works like following:

**1** - The first three digits represent the day;

**2** - The last two digits represent the hour:minute:second.

**Example1:** The first row have the code 19501, so the 195 represent the 1st of January of 2009 and the 01 part represents the time from 00:00:00 to 00:29:59;

**Example2:** In the second row i have the code 19502 which is the 1st of January of 2009 from 00:30:00 to 00:59:59;

**Example3:** Another example, 19711 would be the 3rd of January of 2009 from 05:00:00 to 05:29:59;

**Example4:** The last row is the code 73048, which represent the 20th of June of 2010 from 23:30:00 to 23:59:59.

Any ideas in how can I convert this 5 digit code into a proper datetime format?

Comment: how `5` from `195` takes place in `the 1st of January of 2009` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Is just an integer number that represent that day of the year. `195` is the `1st of January of 2009`. `196` is the `2nd of January of 2009`. `197` is the `3rd of January of 2009`, and so on. If you do the calculation, the last row have `730`, hence `730-195 = 535` days of data. So, if `195` is the `1st of January of 2009`, then adding `535 days` to that, should give us the date `20th of June of 2010`.

Comment: you _really_ need to explain the translation/business logic in more detail. I've read it twice and it makes little sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your column is numeric.

```
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({'code': [19501, 19502, 19711, 73048]})
df['days'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['code']//100, 'D')
df['half-hours'] = df['code']%100
df['hours'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['half-hours']//2, 'h')
df['minutes'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['half-hours']%2*30, 'm')

base_day = dt.datetime(2009, 1, 1) - dt.timedelta(days = 195)

df['dt0'] = base_day + df.days + df.hours + df.minutes - dt.timedelta(minutes = 30)
df['dt1'] = base_day + df.days + df.hours + df.minutes - dt.timedelta(seconds = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution, add the days to `2008-06-20`, add the (time-1)*30min;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'code': [19501, 19502, 19711, 73048]})

d, t = df['code'].divmod(100)

df['datetime'] = (
   pd.to_timedelta(d, unit='D')
     .add(pd.Timestamp('2008-06-20'))
     .add(pd.to_timedelta((t-1)*30, unit='T'))
)
```

*NB. this gives you the start of the period, for the end replace `(t-1)*30` by `t*30-1`.*

Output:

```
    code            datetime
0  19501 2009-01-01 00:00:00
1  19502 2009-01-01 00:30:00
2  19711 2009-01-03 05:00:00
3  73048 2010-06-20 23:30:00
```